# New Module title language constant

Tags: module

Where does this title text comes from? I checked all .ini and .sys.ini files, but when editing the title to see if i got it, nothing changes

I can edit the description seen there, but title always stays same.

[image]

Comment: OK, the title (in contrast to the description) is getting loaded from the manifest cache in the database. purging cache in extension managment refreshes it if changed. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

The constant is MOD_ARTICLES_CATEGORIES and it comes from the language file  `..\language\en-GB\mod_articles_categories.sys.ini`

Changing the value in the sys.ini will change it on the next page load without refreshing any Cache or other settings in my almost vanilla Joomla instance I use for testing.

The constant MOD_ARTICLES_CATEGORIES does also appear in the `..\language\en-GB\mod_articles_categories.ini` but that is not used for the page shown in your question, it is used as the name of the Module that you see when editing the created module.

Looking in `..\administrator\components\com_modules\src\Model\SelectModel.php` you can see it is getting the Name of the module and replacing the constant as expected during the `getItem()` function.

The manifest_cache field is also retrieved into the property called `xml` but that just contains the constants for title and description, neither have the replacements stored. Thus I don't think your issue relates to the manifest cache or is altered by refreshing the manifest cache.

As part of the `getItem()` function it does attempt to store/retrieve the items from a cache as part of the normal `ListModel` `getItems()` function so perhaps you have some other cache issues happening.